# Counting pairs $(a,b)$ with $a^2 +b^2 = t^2$ and $a,b \lt 15$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> How many  pairs $(a,b)$ are there,such that $a^2 +b^2 = t^2$ where $a,b,t \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a,b \lt 15$?

I need a "fast" approach for solving this problem that could be work under a minute.

Comment: The fastest I know is if you know the basic Pythagorean triples:  the only two are (3,4,5) and (5,12,13).  Then you can multiply (3,4,5) by 2 or 3 and interchange a and b.  Makes 8.  Or do you include 0 in $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Ross Millikan:$a$ and $b$ are non-zero positive integer,however the answer is stated as $9$ but I guess may be a typo?!

Comment: @FoolForMath: since $a\ne b$ and you can switch in any pair, the answer must be even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only $2$ such *primitive* pairs by inspection:

- $(3,4)$
- $(5,12)$

Thus one also has:

- $(6,8)$
- $(9,12)$

There are thus $4$ pairs $(a,b)$ with $a,b < 15$.

*Added:* As pointed out by Ross in the comments to the original question, I did not account for the trivial swapping of $a$ and $b$.  This then makes $8$ such pairs.  Furthermore, if one includes $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, then $0^2 + a^2 = t^2$ is also a solution when $a = \pm t$.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the answers I would look at a list of [Pythagorean Triples.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple)

P.S. - Why do you need to solve this in under 1 minute?

Comment: Because that's the time you get to solve a question for which I am preparing for :)

Comment: Oh, well good luck with whatever it is.

Comment: Thanks I need it,this method of exams sucks though,not much room to show creativity in proofs and problem solving everything boils down to smart choosing of options and some mumbo-jumbo with calculations:/